# How to run Javah from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

So I'm trying to run the 'javah' tool on a compiled .class file in Eclipse, but I have no idea how to do it. The examples I found simply said something along the lines of 'run javah on your class...' but I don't really know where I'd find such a command line in Eclipse.

If someone can give me a set of idiot proof instructions get this done in Eclipse, I'd be grateful.

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269511/how-to-configure-javah-tool-in-eclipse/14855418#14855418 Hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

AFAIK Eclipse does not integrate javah by default. You have to set it up as external tool yourself.

1. Create a new external tool
2. Set the path to javah (on linux this
   was /user/bin/javah)
3. Set the working dir to `${project_loc}/bin/` where bin is your Projects output directory
4. Add `${java_type_name}` to the arguments

With this setup you can call javah as external tool on any java file in the Package explorer.
The generated header files currently land in the bin dir, this can be changed by adding the -d option.

Comment: Is ${java_type_name} a pre-existing variable?

Comment: @sparkFinder I just checked the documentation, it is not listed with the default workspace variables - It could be limited to Java projects.

Comment: I get Error: Could not find class file for 'WinLockUnlock.Happy'. where happy is my class name.

Comment: Found a post saying it should be -jni ${java_type_name} 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168033/using-javah-jni-with-an-eclipse-project-structure?rq=1

Comment: Also found a post stating that the "working directory" should be <project>/bin/classes/ not just /bin/ - this worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a sample command line:

```
javah -classpath /path/to/project/classes com.mycompany.MyClass
```

/path/to/project/classes - This is the 'Output folder' from the `Source` tab of `Java Build Path` properties page for you project.

It may be relative to the directory from where you are running javah.

You may use `-verbose` flag to see more details about what's going on.