# Using javah -jni with an Eclipse project structure

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface, external-tools

I need to know if I'm doing the things in a wrong way.

I have the following project structure (a pretty standard one):

[image]

then I've configured `javah` as external tool like this:

[image]

When I run the external tool on `OSManager4Windows.java` I was expecting to find `it_univpm_quickbackup_utils_OSManager4Windows.h` in `bin/it/univpm/quickbackup/utils/` but it is inside `bin`. Is that correct? Shouldn't be inside the same directory of the .class file?

Comment: Thanks for your screenshot - it helped me a lot. Just a note - maybe it'll help someone else someday - I had to set the Working Directory to /bin/classes/ before my header file was created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that javah generates the header file on the directory that the command was executaded (which you specified the bin folder). It makes sense to generate all headers in the same folder because usually c/c++ project put all of headers in the same folder.

However, if you want specific folders, the following command generate the headers in the specific src folder.

```
-d "${workspace_loc}${system_property:file.separator}${container_path}" ${java_type_name}
```