# How to generate JNI header file in Eclipse

Tags: java, c, eclipse, header, java-native-interface

I am using Eclipse to generate a JNI header file. I looked in `program files\java\jre6\bin` and  found a lot of **.exe** and **.dll** files, but I couldn't find the command `javah`  which was in the documentation for using JNI to create bindings to C libraries.
Any help?

Comment: Check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483959/javah-error-android-app-activity-not-found/25989225#25989225

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the following panel to define a new external tool for javah.exe.

Point "Location" to the javah.exe tool.

Set "Working Directory" to

```
${workspace_loc:/${project_name}/bin}
```

Set "Arguments" to:

```
-classpath ${project_classpath} -v -d ${workspace_loc:/${project_name}/src} ${java_type_name}
```

[image]

To run the tool, highlight the java source file in package explorer and run the tool.

[image]

Press F5 to refresh th project to see the newly generated file.

Comment: can you please explain the arguments... that will be really helpful... thanks

Comment: Click the "Variables.." button. The description for each is listed there.

Answer (score 2):

Just some info...

Unfortunately the solution above did not work out for me, but the solution in this thread did:

[Using javah -jni with an Eclipse project structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168033/using-javah-jni-with-an-eclipse-project-structure/4282265#4282265)

With the above mentioned arguments, I got:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
 Not a valid class name:path/to/project`

I found out, that the problem was a space character in the path to my project. Wrapping the paths in quotes did help for the solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Location

// javah.exe path

**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\javah.exe**

Working Directory

**${workspace_loc:/${project_name}/bin}**

Arguments

**-classpath ${project_classpath} -v -d ${workspace_loc:/${project_name}/jni} ${java_type_name}**

*open java class and run tools*

Comment: what is the path for javah in linux ubuntu 16?