# Javah Error android.app.Activity not found

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, javah

I'm trying to create a .h header file for a simple NDK project. Using cygwin I browse to `myprojectDIR\jni` directory, then execute this command:

```
javah -o com_myproject_MyActivity.h -classpath  myprojectDIR\bin\classes com.myproject.MyActivity
```

then this error message appears:

```
Error: cannot access android.app.Activity
class file for android.app.Activity not found
```

I have a native method inside `MyActivity` class, so I tried to create a new class called `NativeAccess` (does not extend any class from the android SDK) and it worked fine, the .h file was created, ndk-build and test on device where successful!

So my problem is that I need my native methods inside android activities and services that I create, but I cant do that because the `Javah` command cannot access classes from inside the android-sdk itself. Please notice that I'm using (Windows-7 x64) and I have these environment variables:

```
ANDROID_NDK : C:\Android\android-ndk-r7b
ANDROID_SDK : C:\Android\android-sdk
ANT_HOME    : C:\ANT\apache-ant-1.8.3
JAVA_HOME   : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02
PATH        : %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_SDK%\tools;%ANDROID_SDK%\platform-tools;%ANDROID_NDK%;%ANT_HOME%\bin; (other unrelated stuff)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to include the android platform jar(s) in the classpath you use with this tool.  If your task is particularly simple you might just create the headers by hand, using the ndk samples as a guide.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I did thought about adding the classpth of the android jar(s) with the javah tool, but I couldn't find how to do that..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try adding to your classpath:

```
-classpath <android-sdk-location>/platforms/android-8.jar
```

Comment: Path changed. now it must be `sdk/platforms/android-10/android.jar`

Answer (score 14):

I found it, this is how it goes:

```
javah -o com_myproject_MyActivity.h -classpath <android-sdk-location>/platforms/android-8.jar;myprojectDIR\bin\classes com.myproject.MyActivity
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following in Eclipse,

Go to > Run | External Tools| External Tool Configurations
   Under Program create new configuration by clicking small icon.

Name it.

Location would be : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin\javah.exe

Working Directory would be: ${workspace_loc:/My_First_NDK/bin/classes} and

Arguments would be: -classpath ${workspace_loc:/My_First_NDK/bin/classes} -bootclasspath "C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140624\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar" -v -d ${workspace_loc:/My_First_NDK/jni} com.mypackage.ndk.HelloNDK

[image]

Comment: For Android Studio use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52527212/2573138

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate native header files `javah` needs:

- your classes (usually under `build/intermediates/classes`)
- Android classes (usually under `$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-%ver%/android.jar`)

So you simply pass them in `-classpath` argument

The main challenge for me was basically passing both of them - you have to use `:` as a separator and paths must be absolute.
See [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javah.html)

Thus you may end up with something like this: 
`javah -classpath <full path to app>build/intermediates/classes/debug:<full path to sdk>/platforms/android-26/android.jar com.myproject.MyActivity`

Answer (score -1):

I found it, this is how it goes:

```
   E:\workspeaceResearch\DAMMADARJNI\src>javah -classpath "E:\Software\sdk\platform
   s\android-19/platforms/android-8.jar"; -jni com.dammadar.jni.Home_Screen
```