# javah error : cannot access activity

Tags: android, android-ndk, javah

I was trying to make a .h file using Javah for my Android NDK application.I am using cygwin to do the same for me.

Fixing the workspace to bin folder of my current application, I executed this command :-

```
javah -classpath /cygdrive/c/Android/android-sdk/platforms/android.jar myNDK\bin\classes my.first.NDK.MyNDKActivity
```

However, it is consistently giving the following error :-

```
error: cannot access myNDKbinclasses
class file for myNDKbinclasses not found
javadoc: error - Class myNDKbinclasses not found.
error: cannot access my.first.NDK.MyNDKActivity
class file for my.first.NDK.MyNDKActivity not found
javadoc: error - Class my.first.NDK.MyNDKActivity not found.
Error: No classes were specified on the command line.  Try -help.
```

Can anyone help me in solving this issue ?

I also tried to go to the folder containing the java file and execute the javah there, but still I was getting same error :-

```
error: cannot access MyNDKActivity
class file for MyNDKActivity not found
javadoc: error - Class MyNDKActivity not found.
Error: No classes were specified on the command line.  Try -help.
```

That somehow depicts the problem is due to some permission problem, I guess.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483959/javah-error-android-app-activity-not-found/25989225#25989225

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I resolved my issue. There was a problem with the classpath I was using. Here goes the final solution :-

1. Where to execute the command from `$PROJECT_DIRECTORY/src`
2. The ant part of the Android build system actually places the class files in `bin/classes`. So the classpath should be of form $PROJECT_DIRECTORY/bin/classes
3. `javah -classpath ../bin/classes my.first.NDK.MyNDKActivity`

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing a separator on your classpath:

```
javah -classpath /cygdrive/c/Android/android-sdk/platforms/android.jar:myNDK/bin/classes my.first.NDK.MyNDKActivity
```

Comment: Still getting the same error error: cannot access my.first.NDK.MyNDKActivity
class file for my.first.NDK.MyNDKActivity not found
javadoc: error - Class my.first.NDK.MyNDKActivity not found.
Error: No classes were specified on the command line.  Try -help.

Comment: This error msg would suggest that your classpath is incorrect. From the current directory, do `ls myNDK/bin/classes`, can you see your `my` folder?

Comment: I can see 'my' folder, but that takes me to outside of my project folder. Is that OK ? I think I need to stay in my bin folder ?

Comment: Thanks for help(+1) ! I had issue with my class path

Answer (score 1):

What is android.jar is doing in your line?!

Also, MyNDKActivity is the class which contains **native** signatures?

I used javah in this form (its works for me):

```
javah -d output/ -classpath /home/bod/path/to/eclipse/workspace/project/classes com.myapp.NDKBridge
```

where:

**-d output/** is directory to collect generated headers

**-classpath /home/.../classes** - folder with classes in your project

**com.myapp.NDKBridge**  - name of class which declare *native* signatures.

Comment: I am totally new to this NDK. So, where should I  execute these commands, in which folder ? On changing my command too, I got the same error

Comment: Thanks for help(+1) ! I had issue with my class path

Answer (score 1):

maybe it can work!add the option [-bootclasspath] of your sdk path.

> javah -bootclasspath /home/lmdyyh/development/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar -classpath bin/classes -d jni com.myndk.Myndk