# Javah: Error: cannot access android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, java-native-interface, javah

I have a problem with javah, I have read about 4 or 5 stakcoverflow posts with the error "solved" but anything works for me.

**My problem:**

When i execute the javah command i have this error:

```
Error: cannot access android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
  class file for android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity not found
```

**What I have tried:**

This is the command that I have tested:

```
C:\Users\MyUser\workspace3\PruebaApp\jni\include>javah -classpath ../../bin/classes;C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-14\android.jar -o ACK.h com.test.prueba.ACK
```

I have tried too the same command with only "/" and only "\" for separating direcotries.

I have tried it with android-11, android-14, and android-21.

I have tried to add the following external jars to my project:
"android-support-v4.jar" and "android-support-v7-appcompat.jar"

I have tried to do it creating a external build configuration with eclipse, like here: [Javah Error android.app.Activity not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483959/javah-error-android-app-activity-not-found)

**Tools I'm using**

I'm working with eclipse juno, on windows 8.1.

The folder from which I executed the command is {project_dir}/jni/include. I have tried it from different folders, modifying the command correctly.

The .java file that contains the native function is "ACK.java" in the package: "com.test.prueba"

In the project, the android library that I'm using is android 5.0.1

What can I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have "solved" my problem. I have put the absolut paths to the missing files: "android-support-v7-appcompat" and "android-support-v4". The result javah command is: javah  -classpath ../../bin/classes;<path_to_android_sdk>/sdk/platforms/android-14/android.jar;<path_to_android_sdk>/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar;<path_to_android_sdk>/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs/android-support-v4.jar -o X.h com.test.prueba.ACK.                            But the problem is still being that i need to write all above, why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The native methods declared in your java class is enough for generating JNI header. In your example, the command `javah`'s option `-classpath` is not very useful. Suppose `com/test/prueba/ACK.java` is the class you process to generate JNI header. You can change the working directory to `{project_dir}\src`, execute the command

```
javah com.test.prueba.ACK
```

the corresponding JNI header file `com_test_prueba_ACK.h` will be created in the current directory.

Comment: You saved my day! Such a simple command and no one has marked this answer up! Thanks a lot.

Comment: how come i get the error `Error: Could not find class file for com.test.prueba.ACK.`?

Comment: @lifeevader This was the example from the asker, you should change it to your real class name.

Comment: yeah I was just giving an illustration of my problem using his code

Answer (score 2):

You should write full path of `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` and `android-support-v4.jar` in classpath parameter.

Comment: These JAR files are in Android/Sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs/

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look to my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52527212/2573138
which integrates in Android Studio the way described by [image]alijandro.