# Generate C header file (*.h) for native method implementation JNI in android studio

Tags: android, gradle, header, java-native-interface, javah

How to generate C header file (*.h) containing the function prototype for the native method implementation JNI in Android studio while build automatically?

Thank You

Comment: By calling `javah` from your build script?

Comment: Thank you sir for point out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume you have a project HelloNative

```
HelloNative
   |-build/intermediate/classes/debug  (you get this directory upon project build)
   |-app/src/main/jni
        /src/main/java/com/planets/mercury/HelloNativeActivity.java
```

And you want to generate the header file for HelloNativeActivity.java --> do this

```
cd HelloNative

javah -d app/src/main/jni -classpath /Users/john-smith/Android/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar:app/build/intermediates/classes/debug com.planets.mercury.HelloNativeActivity
```

Replace john-smith and android sdk path with what it is on your own machine. 
For the android jar file. You can use whatever is your choice.

Eg. android-19, or android-21

Answer (score 5):

I suggest creating an External Tool.

Go to **File->Settings->Tools->External Tools** 
and add a new tool. Fill the dialog form (use "Insert Macro" button )

- *Name*: javah
- *Description*: Generates the jni header file
- *Program*: $JDKPath$\bin\javah
- *Arguments*: -d $SourcepathEntry$..\cpp\ -v $FileClass$
- *Working Directory*. $SourcepathEntry$

Leave the other options unmodified.

[image]

Now you can select your class in the *Project Explorer*, right click and, from the context menu, launch the External Tool->javah.

The header file will be created in the *cpp* folder of your project (as suggested for Android Studio Native development) but you will need to browse the folder in order to see it.

Credits to http://kn-gloryo.github.io/Build_NDK_AndroidStudio_detail/ 
(modified to be more consistent with more recent SDK and Android Studio)
and to [Javah: Error: cannot access android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385146/javah-error-cannot-access-android-support-v7-app-actionbaractivity)

Comment: It seems to be missing a backslash on the arguments. This worked for me: -d $SourcepathEntry$\..\cpp\ -v $FileClass$

Answer (score 2):

For the Generation of the header file in the android studio please follow the given few steps.

```
1) Open Android Studio Terminal
   (At Left Bottom Corner Given Terminal Tab)

2) type this command first
   (cd app/src/main)
   it is located to the your main source directory.

3) now type this command in the termial for the generation of the header file
   (javah -d cpp -classpath ../../build/intermediates/classes/debug <your_packagename>.<class_name>)
```

Comment: And in the meantime some intern broke compatibility and changed the path to the generated classes in Android Studio 4.1 to  "build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes"