# Calling C++ dll from Java

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

I'm using Java for a small app. It's a rewrite of an existing MFC project. There is an existing dll that I need to change to enable access from Java using JNI. All of this Java stuff is new to me, so I'm having a little trouble and feeling rather dense when I read other forum posts. In the existing dll I have a function like this:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool Create()
{
     return TRUE;
}
```

Dumb question time. How do I properly set it up to be called by Java?

I tried this:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Create()
{
     return TRUE;
}
```

I'm including jni.h and everything compiles fine. However, when I call it from Java I get UnsatisfiedLinkError. I'm calling it from Java using this:

```
public static native boolean CreateSession();

System.load("D:\\JavaCallTest.dll");
Create();
```

Could someone kindly push me in the proper direction? I sincerely appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: Have you looked at the Sun example? http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniexamp.html

Comment: Alternatively, you can use JNA instead of JNI since you have a C dll that can be loaded by JNA.

Comment: Please post the exception that is thrown...

Comment: Use javah to generate the C headers, as Jörn Horstmann mentions below -- or avoid JNI entirely. An easy alternative is JNA.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had thought about using JNA, but I want to keep any extras to a minimum, so I thought I'd better use JNI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to include the Java class name and path in your native code, for example if your native method was declared in Java as:

```
public class NativeCode {
    public static native boolean CreateSession();
}
```

and the class path was (for example) `com.example.NativeCode` you would declare your method in native as follows:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_example_NativeCode_CreateSession(JniEnv* env, jclass clazz)
{
    return JNI_TRUE;
}
```

All JNI methods have a JNIEnv pointer and class as their first two parameters.

Comment: That was it. It seems to be working now. We'll see what kind of issues I run into when I'm not dealing with a simple function like this. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @GooseSerbus what about parameters used public static native boolean CreateSession(?,?);

Comment: @Aniket parameters are added onto the parameters in the C method e.g.: `public static native boolean CreateSession(boolean, Object);`
would be `JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_example_NativeCode_CreateSession(JniEnv* env, jclass clazz, jboolean b, jobject o)`

Answer (score 2):

A static native method still needs at least two parameters:

```
JNIEnv *env
jclass clazz
```

The function name also has to correspond the the java package structure.

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_com_example_CreateSession(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz)
```

Ideally, you would use the `javah` tool to create a header file from the java class declaring the native method and then implement the declared function prototypes.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that javah should be used to generate the function signatures.

Comment: Found this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3452258/978528) and setup Eclipse to run javah. Working good now. Now I have to implement the rest of the stuff. Hopefully will be straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem - an existing C-Codebase which i needed to access from Java. It paid off for me, to get familiar with [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/), a tool to generate an intermediate C++ DLL (which calls the C-Code), plus Java-Code that is calling into the C++ DLL.

If you have more than just 1 function of the DLL to wrap, it might pay off to check out this tool, otherwise you'd have to get familiar with JNI...

**EDIT**:

It seems like your DLL is not found by the `System.load()` call. You might want to try `System.loadLibrary()`, but note that your DLL must then be located in the path denoted by the Java system property `java.library.path`.
Also dont pass the full filename in this case, but just the filename without extension.

Comment: It was finding the DLL, but I didn't have my function properly declared. I'll have to look into SWIG. Thanks for the tip.