# Call a c++ function that returns a int value from java

Tags: java, android, c++, function, return

So the title explains everything you need to know... I tried googling for 2 hours but I just cant find a page where it shows you how to do like example I have a code that calculates the screen size in cpp and I want to call it in java to use it(obviously)
**EDIT:**
I just have to put the cpp file name or register it in the Android.mk file... My bad still learning CPP android apps

Comment: export your c++ function in a dll see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485896/calling-c-dll-from-java

Comment: Google the JNI (Java native interface)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling C++ dll from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485896/calling-c-dll-from-java)

Comment: Please remove the downvotes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to place the cpp file name in the Android.mk file... This is my first time so sorry... 
Fixed code:
C++

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

extern "C"
{

    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_net_pixeldroidof_addonedit_MainActivity_getScreenY(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz)
    {
        int number = 30;
        return number;
    }
}
```

Java

```
public native static int getScreenY();
//And you can start calling it(example: getScreenY() will now return the value from the cpp)
```